# SQL multiple relation but only the latest shall be considered to join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to join multiple tables and I did it even that I started with SQL a week ago.

But now I found out that we have a messy database and I have multiple related prices for a "block".

My task:

> get the LATEST activeprice for each block. So i only need activeprice_id 30 for block_id 123

Unfortunatelly my database (i only can consume tables and run queries, i can´t change anything on the db) brings multiple activeprice_id for one parent pricehistory_id.

I want to have one row for each block that shows (block_id, latestprice, firstprice) if firstprice equals latest price (so only one activeprice id) first price shall equal the latest price.

I have tried to calculate the MAX based on created from Activeprice but somehow it didn't work out and I still have more than one activeprice.price for one pricehistory.

Help please.

I have 3918 Blocks but I always get 4030 prices(rows)

```
CREATE TABLE activeprice (id INT,
                            price DECIMAL(10,2),
                            created DATE,
                            pricehistory_id DECIMAL(10,2));
INSERT INTO activeprice VALUES
(25, 500.00, '2022-01-04',1),
(30, 750.00, '2022-02-03',1),
(50, 1000.00, '2022-02-05',2),;

SELECT * FROM activeprice;

CREATE TABLE block (id INT,
                   created DATE,
                   pricehistory_uuid INT);
INSERT INTO block VALUES
(123,'2022-01-04',abcdefg),
(321,'2022-02-05',hijklmn),;
SELECT * FROM block;

CREATE TABLE pricehistory (id INT,
                   created DATE,
                   activeprice_id INT,
                   uuid INT);
INSERT INTO pricehistory VALUES
(1,'2022-01-04',25,abcdefg),
(1,'2022-02-03',30,abcdefg),
(2,'2022-02-05',50,hijklmn),;
SELECT * FROM pricehistory;
```

My query

```
WITH ap_latest AS
(
SELECT
   MAX(ap.created),
   ap.id,
   ph.uuid
FROM activeprice AS ap
LEFT JOIN pricehistory AS ph
ON ph.id = ap.pricehistory_id
WHERE ph.uuid IN
   (
    SELECT b.pricehistory_uuid
    FROM block AS b
    LEFT JOIN pricehistory AS ph
    ON ph.uuid = b.pricehistory_uuid)
GROUP BY ap.id, ph.uuid
)

SELECT b.id AS b_id
     , ap.price AS cb_price_latest
FROM block AS b
LEFT JOIN pricehistory AS ph
ON ph.uuid = b.pricehistory_id
LEFT JOIN ap_latest AS ap
ON ap.pricehistory_id = ph.id;
```

Does this makes any sense?

I don´t get behind your query, so i am not able to convert it into my statement. thank you all for our patience

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are two different DBMSs. Remove unrelated tag.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?  (I don't think the query will run on both...)

Comment: @Akina thank you for you quick comment. 
I should clarify that i don´t have permission to change anything in the db. I only have analytics access and can run queries on snowflake in a db replica.

To be honest i don´t know what CTE means and i need to look up enumerate command first

Comment: *i don´t know what CTE means* CTE == Common Table Expression == WITH clause.

Comment: You do however have permission to correct the tags you have associated with this question - please do so.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified example for MySQL version 8+:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN NOT GROUPING(price_date)
            THEN sale.product_id
            WHEN GROUPING(sale.product_id)
            THEN 'All products'
            ELSE CONCAT('Product ', sale.product_id)
            END product_id,
       sale.sale_date,
       SUM(sale.product_amount) product_amount,
       price.price,
       price.price_date,
       SUM(sale.product_amount * price.price) product_cost
FROM sale
JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT *
               FROM price_history
               WHERE sale.product_id = price_history.product_id
                 AND sale.sale_date >= price_history.price_date
               ORDER BY price_history.price_date DESC LIMIT 1 ) price
GROUP BY sale.product_id,
         sale.sale_date,
         price.price,
         price.price_date WITH ROLLUP
HAVING GROUPING(sale.sale_date) OR NOT GROUPING(price_date)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=09425796f8378593df801d09a6d59885

In SQL Server - do the same with `CROSS APPLY`.